# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'addStudent' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

Here is form.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Student</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form action="addStudent" commandName="addStudent" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name">Name:</form:label></td> <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="email">Email:</form:label></td> <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="age">Age:</form:label></td> <td><form:input path="age"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addStudent", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("addStudent") Student student) {
    System.out.println("Saving Info...");
    System.out.println("Name: "+student.getName());
    System.out.println("Email: "+student.getEmail());
    System.out.println("Age: "+student.getAge());
    return "form";
}
```

Here is Student model

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private int age;
    private int id;

    public Student() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I guess there is no need for web.xml or dispatcher-servlet.xml . Every thing is correctly binded, I mean commandName is right in jsp. ModelAttribute is correct in controller then why contol is not reaching controller? :(

Please help. I have already wasted half of the day on this.
PS:I am new to Spring and stackoverflow.

**EDIT:**

after suggestions, my code look like this:

controller method:

```
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result) {
```

jsp form:

```
<form:form action="addStudent" commandName="student" method="post">
```

**EDIT:**

resolved it myself
added this method for modelattibute

```
@ModelAttribute("student")
    public Student getForm() {
        return new Student();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the commandName and modelAttribute String are the same that's fine.

likewise im a newbie to Spring and stuff.. 
but I'm guessing it cant find the correct request mapping since you have /addStudent in the request mapping and just addStudent in the form action. that is fine if the form is in context root. 
could you try checking that out?

Also please add a BindingResult object in the arg list
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("addStudent") Student student, BindingResult result)

Comment: Still not working... Whatever you mentioned is not a problem I guess